# Nero2016 doesn't recognize my Blu ray drive as being able to burn Blu-rays

Tags: windows-10, burning, nero

Purchased Nero 2016 recently with the intent to burn BluRays for archiving.

I have an Asus N56VZ laptop running Windows 10. The combo drive is a MATSHITA-BD-CMB UJ160 which I have been told by Asus tech support as being Blu-ray comatible.

However, whenever I try and burn a Blu-ray disc I get the following error in **Nero BurningROM 2016** (and I definitely have the correct recorder chosen in the recorder drop down).

> Sorry, the recorder supports only the following disc type(s):
>       CD R/RW, DVD R/RW, DVD DL, DVD RAM, but the compilation can only be written on a BD-R/RE, BD DL, BDXL. Please select a different
>   recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Nero is correct in what it says, that drive, the Matshita BD-CMB UJ160, cannot write to Blu-ray discs, it can only read them... It can write to DVD and CD media. Asus support is also correct, the drive is "Blu-Ray compatible", meaning it can read Blu-Ray discs but not write to them. This is a common type of optical drive in modern laptops, hence the name "combo", it is a combo DVD-R/RW read/writer and a Blu-Ray reader.

```
Drive : MATSHITA BD-CMB UJ160B  
Type : Blu-ray COMBO DL  
Buffer Size : 2 MB  
Mechanism : Tray  
Interface : SATA-1  
Read Speed : BD: 6x, DVD: 8x, CD: 24x  
Write Speed : DVD-R: 8x max. DVD+R: 8x max. DVD-RW: 6x max. DVD+RW: 8x max. DVD-R DL: 6x max. DVD+R9: 6x max. DVD-RAM: 5x max. CD-R: 24x max. CD-RW: 24x max  

Read CD Text : Yes  
Return C2 Pointers : Yes  
Read CD-R : Yes 
Read CD-RW : Yes  
Read DVD-ROM : Yes  
Read DVD-RAM : Yes  
Read DVD-R : Yes  
Read DVD-RW : Yes  
Read DVD-R DL : Yes  
Read DVD+R : Yes  
Read DVD+RW : Yes  
Read DVD+R DL : Yes  
Read BD-ROM : Yes  
Read BD-R : Yes  
Read BD-RE : Yes  
Read HD DVD-ROM : No  
Read HD DVD-R : No  
Read HD DVD-R DL : No  
Read HD DVD-RAM : No  
Read HD DVD-RW : No  
Read HD DVD-RW DL : No  
Read HD-BURN : Yes  
Read Digital Audio : Yes  
Read CD+G : Yes  
Read VideoCD : Yes  

Write CD-R : Yes  
Write CD-RW : Yes  
Write DVD-R : Yes  
Write DVD-RW : Yes  
Write DVD-R DL : Yes  
Write DVD+R : Yes  
Write DVD+RW : Yes  
Write DVD+R DL : Yes  
Write DVD-RAM : Yes  
Write BD-R : No  
Write BD-RE : No  
Write HD DVD-R : No  
Write HD DVD-R DL : No  
Write HD DVD-RAM : No  
Write HD DVD-RW : No  
Write HD DVD-RW DL : No  
Write HD-BURN-R : No  
Write HD-BURN-RW : No  

Buffer Underrun Protection : Yes  
Mount Rainier : No  
SolidBurn : No  
Labelflash : No  
LightScribe : No  
Modes : Pa, LTA, LDA, LSA, LRA, LRA, LRA
```

If you look at the write capabilities, they are all "No" for Blu-ray (BD).  It can read Blu-ray, however. You are doing nothing wrong, your computer and Nero are working properly, it is just not capable of what you are trying to do.